# Ruby array conditionnally replacing an item in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am struggling to build a small ruby snippets to compare two arrays and conditionally replace items in one of the array.
I have a "book" model which has titles and titles have chapters. I have an array with all the lines of a book and want to replace the chapters by the corresponding title in this array.

```
def replace_chapters_by_titles(all_lines_of_a_book)
  books = Book.all
  all_lines_of_a_book.each do |line|
    books.each do |chapter|
    if (line =~ /#{book.chapter}/)
    line = "#{book.title}" #this is where I am not sure what I should do
    end
    end
  end
end
```

I guess this has no impact on the array as I am just putting "#{book.title}" in line without pushing anything to the array "all_lines_of_a_book". Could someone help me find the right syntax?

Comment: what's book here? You'd get an undefined variable or method 'book' error. 
The iterator for `books` could be `book` instead of `chapter`?

Comment: ohh yes, book is undefined..do take care of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push to the index where line exists in array, try below code

```
def replace_chapters_by_titles(all_lines_of_a_book)
  books = Book.all
  all_lines_of_a_book.each_with_index do |line, index| # note this
    books.each do |chapter|
      if (line =~ /#{book.chapter}/)
        all_lines_of_a_book[index] = "#{book.title}" # and this
      end
    end
  end
  all_lines_of_a_book # probably you want to return new array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach may help:

```
arr   # => [1, 22, 5, 66, 77, 8, 88, 0] 
subst # => [9,  8, 7,  6,  5, 4,  3, 2]
cond = lambda { |x| x>10 } # condition for substitution
arr.zip(arr.map(&cond)).each_with_index.map do |(a,b),i| 
  if b then subst[i] else a end 
end # => [1, 8, 5, 6, 5, 8, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr   # => [1, 22, 5, 66, 77, 8, 88, 0] 
subst # => [9,  8, 7,  6,  5, 4,  3, 2]

arr.each_index.map { |i| arr[i] > 10 ? subst[i] : arr[i] }
  # => [1, 8, 5, 6, 5, 8, 3, 0]
```

or

```
arr.each_with_index.map { |n,i| n > 10 ? subst[i] : n }
```